# ViewProfile Module does not display for non host users

Tags: dotnetnuke

I have a viewProfile module inside a DNN 8 (08.00.01 (236)) website.  This website was created at this version and was not upgraded.

When a non host users logs into the site the content of the viewProfile module is hidden due to a display:none style being added (I assume by javascript and knockout.js) to the wrapping div.  In order to get around this I have added the following script to my page:

```
<script>$(document).ready(function(){ $('[id*="ViewProfile_profileOutput"]').show() } );</script>​
```

This is super hacky and I don't like it, but i was against a deadline and needed to make it happen.

Does anyone know why the ViewProfile Module does not display content to non host users?  Or do you think this is a bug I should report?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely a bug, but you're also not on the latest DNN8 release, that bug might already be addressed by doing a simple upgrade.

Comment: haha, simple upgrade, that's a good one.  I will post back if the upgrade solves the issue but I don't have it planned just yet

Comment: Upgrades are easy :D